# Inconsistent indentation with YAML

Tags: server, 20.04, configure

While trying to set up my Ubuntu Server, I've stumbled upon this error when typing
**Netplan Generate**

```
Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
```

But it just shows

```
                  ^
```

I have no Idea where the error is.

My Code is:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    addresses: [192.168.136.1/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.136.1
    nameservers: 
      addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
      search: []
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp2s2:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        'SSID'
          password: 'password'
```

Please Note that:
The ethernets part was there when I opened it for the first time, so I only configured the wifis part.

I've left the SSID and the password away for obvious reasons.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe you're missing a colon after the wireless interface and again after SSID. I generally use double-quotes rather than single quotes with the SSID ... 

Comment: Me too @matigo I advice to use double quotes. and .... https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbd763fb ftw ;-) acc. to link: error at wlp2s2 a , made it valid ;)

Comment: Indentation is bad too, look at examples: https://netplan.io/examples/

Comment: @matigo I edited it but now it says --> Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation)

Comment: @pasmanpasmański Sorry I kinda messed it up a bit while writing the question. I edited it. now it looks like the code.

Comment: @matigo Nvm, it I changed the code a bit. But now it doesn't really work. It only says configuring when I type **networkctl**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first comment made two points:

   [image: Missing something ...]
2. The second comment corroborated something in the first, supplied a tool to validate the YAML against, and pointed to a specific line:

   [image: YAML Validation]
3. Using the YAML validator, invalid YAML was confirmed:

   [image: Missing a colon]
4. Adding a colon resolves the issue:

   [image: One-Two Punch]

Comment: even after the colon it still didn't work. I simply removed the single quotes from the SSID and the password